# Integral of a function with big power $\int\frac{dx}{\cos^8 x}$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate this function and I know that $\cos(x)$ in denominator with even power we should use z=tanx to solve the integral.
But I'm not succeeding in solving it. 
Any ideas ?

$$\int\frac{1}{\cos^8 x} \ \mathrm{d}x$$

after reading the comments I came to that using t=tanx leads me to this integral :

$$\color{red}{\int (1+t^2)^3 dt}$$

how can we continue ?

Comment: Write the integrand as $\sec^2 x\sec^6 x$. Then write $\sec^6 x=(\sec^2 x)^3$ in terms of $\tan x$ using a [Pythagorean identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity#Tabulation_of_derivations).

Comment: The substitution $t=tan(\frac{x}{2})$ should also work.

Comment: Your final answer should come out to be $(\sin x/35\cos^7 x) (16\cos^6 x + 8 \cos^4 x +6 \cos^2 x + 5)$

Comment: I edited the question by adding $dx$ in the title.  If you're confused about why that matters, look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200393/what-is-dx-in-integration/200403#200403

Comment: I used $t=tan(\frac{x}{2})$ it just got harder so I see a nice answer down that I used thank you anyway.
Michael thanks for pointing this out for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you simply have $$\int \sec ^6x \sec^2 xdx=\int (1+\tan^2x)^3.\sec^2xdx$$ then use $u=\tan x$ and $du=\sec ^2xdx$ then
$$=\int (1+u^2)^3du
\\=\int (1+3u^2+3u^4+u^6)du$$

Comment: yes so I have now : $\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^3}dt$
how can I continue ?

Comment: Did you understand my first step

Comment: yes, I did my friend
now I'm trying to solve the second step but still not moving ...

Comment: What about the rest

Comment: it seems connected some how to arctan derivative am I right ?

Comment: i edited again, is it clear now

Comment: 100% it was my fault I did not get it .
but now everything is ok thank you !