# Does $f(x)\,dx$ denote multiplication of $f(x)$ by $dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, soft-question

In the integral form $\int \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ does $f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ can be seen as a multiplication of $f(x)$ and $\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: It is "analogous" to multiplication, but the reality of it is somewhat more complicated, just as $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is notation that looks like division.

Comment: I'm asking for "the reality of it"!

Comment: In applications, "seeing" that a given quantity is represented by a certain integral is natural if one views it as a multiplication.

Comment: This is closely related to your previous question [Is $dxdy$ really a multiplication of $dx$ and $dy$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/703212/148175)

Comment: Ultimately at the most basic level $\int f(x) dx$ is just a notation, where the purpose of the $dx$ is little more than to distinguish the variable of integration. For intuition, you might think of the $\int$ as analogous to a summation symbol and the $dx$ as analogous to an infinitesimally small increment, which is what I think Leibnez had in mind when he invented this notation.

Comment: I think this differs a bit from the question "Wahat is $dx$ in integration?", because there the question only asks the nature of $dx$, and here we are searching for the relation (or operation) between a function and $dx$.

Comment: It's a different question, but you can't approach your question without answering the other, and visa versa, so they are essentially equivalent. @Emin

Answer (score 4):

Yes. $\mathrm{d}x$ is a differential form, and the space of differential forms has scalar multiplication by continuous functions, and scalar multiplying $\mathrm{d}x$ by $f(x)$ gives  $f(x) \mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Or you can think of $f(x)$ as a $0$-form. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* a literal product of two numbers.

There are several different "realities of it" from the point of view of advanced mathematics. Until you get to higher mathematics, it is better to think of $dx$ as purely a notational thing. For example what would it mean to try to compute:$$\int_a^b (c^2-x^2)?$$ It would be unclear that $c$ is the constant, and it is $x$ that varies. In this sense, $dx$ is just saying "with $x$ varying" and serves the same purpose as the $i=$ in the notation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (c^2-i^2)$$

which is obviously different from:

$$\sum_{c=1}^n (c^2-i^2)$$

A more advanced notion is one of a differential form. In that sense, $f(x)dx$ *is* the product of $f(x)$, a $0$-form  and  $dx$, a $1$-form. This is a fairly advanced view, however, and it often just feels like raw notation when first learning about them. Differential forms are more useful when you are dealing with multiple variables.

There is also the notion of measure theory, where $dx$ is often generalized to $d\mu$, where $\mu$ is a "measure." In that sense, the $x$ represents the most obvious "measure" on the real line.

Comment: It _is_ a product of one thing that is literally a number and another that might be considered something other than a number.

Comment: No, it is not a product of a number. $f(x)$ is a function, not a number. @MichaelHardy

Comment: For each value of $x$, $f(x)$ is a number, and that is what gets multiplied by $dx$. ${}\qquad{}$  $f$ is a function; $f(x)$ is a number. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry, but $f(x)dx$ is not really a combination of a lot of $f(x_i)dx$ values. That doesn't make any sense, unless you say what $dx$ is. There is a *sense* in which $dx$ is related to localization, but it certainly isn't 'literally' a single number times some thing called $dx$. It is certainly *like* $\sum f(x_i)\delta x$ but it isn't literally that. @MichaelHardy

Comment: In particular, it is not the same thing independent of the structure of $\mathbb R$. For example, define $C$ to be the Cantor set, and define $f(x)=\chi_C(x)$, define $g(x)=\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$. The the mutli-set of values $f(x_1)dx$ and the multi-set of values $g(x_1)dx$ are the same set of values, but $f(x)dx$ and $g(x)dx$ are not the same. It is useless to try to localize at $x_1$ and then *forget* $x_1$. @MichaelHardy

Comment: Yeah it **is** a product of two numbers like when we want to calculate the area or do some Physics Proofs/Calculations! Further detail see : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/200400/134694

Comment: No, it's not, @NeilRoy. If $dx$ is a number, then what number is it? It's a notation *related* to computation of area, but $f(x)dx$ is not a product of two numbers. Also, when commenting on an answer more than a year old, be more specific about what you mean by "it."

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200393/what-is-dx-in-integration/200403#200403).

In particular, if $f(x)$ is in meters per second and $dx$ is in seconds, then $f(x)\,dx$ is in meters, and things like that matter all the time in physics.