# How probability density function is defined

Tags: probability, statistics

The probability of an event, $P(A)$, is a **definite** number.

I can espress $P(A)$ as $P(A)=p(a)da$ where $p(a)$ is the **probability density function**.

However, $da$ is **NOT** a definite value, so how it's possible to get a definite quantity calculating $p(a)da$ and ascertain that effectively $P(A)=p(a)da$  ?

Comment: Who says you can express $P(A)$ as $p(a)da$?

Comment: It is not a problem that is exclusive to probabilities. I suppose you have encountered integrals before and used the same notation. Plus, as Bungo noted, the link between the PDF and the actual probability is not the oone you wrote down. You could have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200393/what-is-dx-in-integration).

Comment: So, how can i calculate the probability of a single event A with the probability density function ? And why is worth using the integral calculus ?

Comment: Is there a random variable somewhere in the picture? Where is this probability density function coming from? Some context would be helpful.

Comment: So, can't i use the probability density function for NON random events ? Why ?

Comment: How do you define your probability density function?

Comment: "The [Probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is used to specify the probability of the random variable falling within a particular range of values, as opposed to taking on any one value. This probability is given by the integral of this variable’s PDF over that range. $\Pr [a \leq X \leq b] = \int _{a}^{b}f_{X}(x)\,dx$."

Comment: Then, using the probability density function i lose the way to find the probability of a single value ? If yes, what is the advantage ?

Comment: If a random variable has a probability density function (which happens if and only if the random variable is absolutely continuous), then the probability that it assumes any single value is zero.

Comment: I have now understood that the probability that it assumes any single value is zero because a real number requires a infinite precision. But, why things work so well with integral calculus ?

Comment: You can compute probabilities using integral calculus by accepting various integration rules and that is fine. As to why integral calculus and probability theory are related is the subject of measure theory. You will need to do a course in that.