# Why does the dx in the integral have algebriac properties?

Tags: calculus, integration

Sometimes I see that

$\int f(x) dx = \int f(x) *dx $

This property is required by u substitution like so:
$ \int f(g(x)) dx = \int \frac {f(u)}{u'} du$

or some fancy integrals like so: $ \int x^{dx} -1 = \int \frac {x^{dx} - 1}{dx} dx$

this property is also used in differential equations and so on.

However I fail to see the rigor behind this. Because dx in this context is defined to be the variable of the anti derivative.

I tried to prove this through riemann sum because dx is directly defined to be multiplying the entire series. But I have failed to so.

I am really confused by this. But I agree that dy/dx can be treated as a fraction

eg:

$ dy = f*dg + g*df $

$ = dy/dx = f*dg/dx + g*df/dx  $

$ = y' = f*g' + g*f'  $

Thus proving product rule.

but not in this context.

Because the "dx" can be easily any other symbol, but as long as it represents the variable "x" of F(x)+c.

this thing has been giving me a headache for a while now.

Comment: Your question is kind of messy so I'm not sure what you really need, but please checkout [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200393) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199) and some "Related" posts.

Comment: Hello and, again, welcome to the Aperture Science computer-aided enrichment center.